# Why can't I get Failfast event and ConcurrentModificationException

Tags: java, multithreading

The following code block is from an article which says the program will produce fail-fast event and throws `ConcurrentModificationException`, because multiple threads are modifying the list through iterator, but I ran it and it runs OK, what is wrong?

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;


public class FastFailTest {

private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
public static void main(String[] args) {


    new ThreadOne().start();
    new ThreadTwo().start();
}

private static void printAll() {
    System.out.println("");

    String value = null;
    Iterator iter = list.iterator();
    while(iter.hasNext()) {
        value = (String)iter.next();
        System.out.print(value+", ");
    }
}


private static class ThreadOne extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        int i = 0;
        while (i<6) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i));
            printAll();
            i++;
        }
    }
}


private static class ThreadTwo extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        int i = 10;
        while (i<16) {
            list.add(String.valueOf(i));
            printAll();
            i++;
        }
    }
}

}
```

Comment: Threads are not some routines that programmers can depend on their running order because OS is managing their running schedule and lifecycle. May be because of the shorter lifecycle of your `ThreadOne` it is being executed totally before the `ThreadTwo` is scheduled to be executed by the OS. So No concurrency happens and no exception is being thrown. You may want to manage a more time consuming jobs in your threads in order to somehow increase the possibility of the concurrent execution and modification on the shared resource.

Comment: An easier way to get it is `for(String s : list) list.remove(s);`. People associate `ConcurrentModificationException` with threads (due to the name), but in most cases it's not caused by concurrent programming at all.

Comment: The exception happens for me. The lesson here is: multithreading errors can be really hard to find by experimentation/testing. The best way to write correct multithreaded code is to just be really careful and think through the logic. Start with the assumption that the code is broken, and prove to yourself that it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I execute the code, sometimes I am getting the CME and sometimes not.

Below are the stack trace and output when I got the exception.
Well, one thing is sure that the time,when both the threads are trying to insert the data ,their time is not conflicting with each other because both of them are taking very less time to populate the list.
I executed the code And I got the exception.

Since ThreadOne can insert values only from [0,5] and Thread Two can insert values only [10,15]
The last Line of output is    [0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException]

I believe that ThreadTwo has completed inserting elements in list, but thread One has added only one element that is 0.

Below is the stack trace.

```
0, 0, 10, 10, 
0, 10, 11, 
0, 10, 11, 12, 
0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 
0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 
0, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
    at com.failfast.FastFailTest.printAll(FastFailTest.java:23)
    at com.failfast.FastFailTest.access$1(FastFailTest.java:17)
    at com.failfast.FastFailTest$ThreadOne.run(FastFailTest.java:34)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the next class for concurrent List
`List newList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList());`

[Synchronized List](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#synchronizedList(java.util.List))